# Listener that has events for when a frame is snapped to the left or right of screen

Tags: java, swing, jframe, listener, windowstate

I know `WindowStateListener` will tell me if a component is maximized vertically, horizontally, or both. At least, it says it will. I do not know how to maximize a window exclusively horizontally or exclusively vertically outside of snapping the window to the left edge or right edge of my screen. Is there another listener for this behavior? Or will I need to make something myself that tracks mouse location in relation to the screen? I made an example program that displays what I've described.

**SSCCE**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowStateListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SnapFrame frame = new SnapFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
class SnapFrame extends JFrame implements WindowStateListener{
    public SnapFrame(){
        super();
        addWindowStateListener(this);
    }


@Override
public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent arg0) {
     //will print a statement for all state change events except snapping to left/right edges of screen
    System.out.println("state changed");
}
}
```

If I wanted to have things triggered by this behavior, and there are no other listeners that have events for this, would a decent idea be to get my screen size and watch my mouse location for when it comes near the edge of my screen?

Comment: 1) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Don't set the size of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()`. 4) For frame positioning, you cannot go by `setLocationByPlatform(true)`.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556) for demo.

Comment: While I agree with darn near everything you say, I whipped this together in less than a minute to illustrate what I've tested to achieve an event when dragging a window to the left or right edge of my screen. I put this together so others can copy, paste, and see what I described. Unless I'm vastly misunderstanding the purpose of an SSCCE, I believe I've posted one already. It's a lot easier to test a "drag this window" scenario if the window appears in the center, away from all edges. Would you not agree?

Comment: An SSCCE is one source file.  Change `public class SnapFrame` to `class SnapFrame` & paste it into the end of the `Main` class source, and it will be an SSCCE. :)

Comment: No, there isn't a listener or functionality that will 1- tell you when your window is snapped to the side of the screen or 2- snap your window to the side. Ive done something like it before, but that was with an undecoracted window though

Comment: I was afraid of that. I don't imagine it'll be terribly difficult to work around it, but I always do a search before I build my own stuff from scratch to try and save me time. :p Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This source detects when the frame is snapped to the top or bottom of screen, using a `ComponentListener`.  I don't know how to configure my Windows to snap to the left or right.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SnapFrame frame = new SnapFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class SnapFrame extends JFrame implements ComponentListener {

    Dimension screenSize;

    public SnapFrame() {
        super();
        screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        addComponentListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        Rectangle r = getBounds();

        if (r.getMinY()==0  || r.getMaxY()==(int)screenSize.getHeight()) {
            System.out.print("Well snap!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent ignore) {}

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent ignore) {}

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent ignore) {}
}
```

### Other tips

- Don't extend frame or other top level containers.  Instead create & use an instance of one.
- Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks much. I am using a JLayeredPane, and so was interested in using all window/component state changes and movements to manually resize components in the JLayeredPane since there's no layout manager. I do appreciate the reply!